# shared database link

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration

While trying to use use DB link for a remote database i got the following error:

```
Oracle error has occurred. Error=(Error in execution of OCI function unused:
retcode = -1 (OCI_ERROR)
ORA-24777: use of non-migratable database link not allowed
ORA-06512: at "MXSADM22.MXS_GET_SMS_SO_DETAILS", line 192
ORA-06512: at line 1
) Line=(1203) File=(ck_BpDataLayer.c) Function=(ck_StoredProcedureCall) Trigger=(NULL)
```

I tried to find solution and found that creating a shared DB link could solve a problem. And it does indeed in my case.

I would like to know if creating a shared DB link would pose any performance or security concern.
we already have other public DB link to the remote database.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with your shared server process at local database. Try to connect using dedicated server process and execute again your procedure. Your remote database doesn't allow your shared server process for executing query. I think you got my point.